# Datalist or Datagrid to display rows of database looking like a table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, datagrid, datalist

I'm working with a sql table that looks like this:

```
    ID Region Store        Sales
    1  MEX    Supermarket  10,000
    2  USA    Supermarket   5,000
    3  MEX    Club         10,000
    4  USA    Direct        1,000
    5  MEX    Direct        4,000
    6  USA    Club              0
```

I have 8 different region options(just 2 here to make it shorter). Also, 3 store options, and I want to display the info like this:

```
    Store        MEX       USA
    Supermarket  10,000    5,000
    Club         10,000        0
    Direct        4,000    1,000
```

So, I don't know what to choose to display the info like a table to compare the sales between the regions in each store segment, which would be the correct sql to call them and order in columns to make it look like the table.

Comment: Good candidate for SQL PIVOT operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good candidate for PIVOT operator. Check this [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx).

For your situation, try this. You can add additional columns besides MEX and USA.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    [Region] ,
                    [Store] ,
                    [Sales]
          FROM      [RegionSales]
        ) rs PIVOT ( SUM(Sales) FOR Region IN ( [MEX], [USA] ) ) AS SalesPerRegion
```

Comment: Thank you!! exactly what i needed!!! now gonna try to calculate and add the total row at the bottom of the table